# MYSQL/Laravel - Select based on condition?

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, eloquent

I'm having a hard time figuring this out:

I have multiple lotteries and a user can participate in each.
Now when selecting the winners I only want to select users which havent won in a lottery before.

```
table lotteries
table "users" (column won is either 0 or 1)
```

How would I do this in mysql, preferably in laravels eloquent?
Thanks!

EDIT: To be more specific: I don't want users to win in multiple lotteries. So if a user won already, he should be excluded from the query. The individual field to check would be "email"

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you keep track of it in a won column on the users table, it's really easy. Here's an example using models in eloquent:

```
$losers = User::where('won', false)->get();
```

Comment: To be more specific: I don't want users to win in multiple lotteries. So if a user won already, he should be excluded from the query.
The individual field to check would be "email".